# how do I lock mysql rows on read

Tags: mysql, concurrency, locking, innodb, race-condition

I have a mysql innodb table that is populated by a script. I'm only able to have one consumer script read the table at a time. For example, there are 10 records in the table, I read all 10, process them, and update a field in the table to indicate they are complete. During the processing, 8 more records have come in, but I cannot have another script consume those without picking up the original 10 again (which have not been marked as complete yet).

Ideally, I'd like to lock the 10 records (not lock the whole table) when they are read - and lock only to 1 consumer of the table since I could see 2 consumers possibly reading them at the same time. Is there a way to do something like this or does anyone have a better idea?

To note - I do not have access to the script that is populating the table, so I am not able to send the records to a queue instead.

Comment: Transactions is what you must be looking for.

Comment: If I read in a transaction and update, yeah I need to do that regardless. But if process A is reading at same time as process B, I don't think it blocks process B from reading, which is what I am trying to do. I should have wrote my question that way, sorry.